# Size of soul in Hinduism texts

Tags: atma

Is there any text mentioning about the size of soul in Hinduism?

If there, then what is the size/volume of soul according to it?

Is it a physical thing and has same size for all organisms?

What I mean is physical dimensional explanation of soul.

Comment: See this answer: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9316/3872

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Brahman in unmanifested state reduce to the size of half a thumb?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9300/how-can-brahman-in-unmanifested-state-reduce-to-the-size-of-half-a-thumb)

Comment: how is that question a duplicate of linked question?

Comment: May be this is the one you want. 

https://harekrishnarevolution.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/the-size-of-the-soul/

Answer (score 4):

The size of the soul is mentioned in the Śvetaśvatara Upanishad.

> बालाग्रशतभागस्य शतधा कल्पितस्य च ।
>
> भागोजीवः स विज्ञेयः स चानन्त्याय क ॥ ५.९ ॥
>
> Know the embodied soul to be a part of the hundredth part of the point
>   of a hair divided a hundred times, and yet it is infinite.

(English translation of Svetasvatara Upanishad by Swami Nikhilananda)

Considering the thickness of the tip of the human hair approximately 1 millimeter. Calculating the size we can around 1 nanometer (i.e. 0.000000001 meter). Since the soul is so tiny, it is not possible to see the spirit soul with the naked eyes.

Comment: A human hair is closer to 100 µm. (100 µm / 100) / 100 = 10 nm